# SEO when subdomains point to the same site?

Tags: seo

My subdomains are going to be city names:

```
miami.mysite.com
newyork.mysite.com
```

I don't know how most sites handle subdomains. My idea is simply to point them all to mysite.com and somehow get the subdomain name with PHP so that I echo the city posts and content with PHP.

Providing all subdomains have different Titles and Description. Will google index each subdomain as a different website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Google will index each one as a separate site. However make sure you consider the pros and cons. Here's a good starting point: http://www.seomoz.org/blog/understanding-root-domains-subdomains-vs-subfolders-microsites

My opinion is go with subfolders (e.g. mysite.com/miami) instead of subdomains, mainly because consolidating inbound links to a single hostname will build more authority over time than if the same link juice is diluted among hundreds of subdomains. Also I think it would be hard to build enough unique content on each subdomain to support or justify having a separate site.